# How does Nord Stream II project fit with Ukraine-EU relationship?

Tags: european-union, ukraine, gas, nord-stream

A local TV short documentary argued that the [Nord Stream II](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nord_Stream) project should be finalized by 2019. I cannot find information to support this, but Wikipedia mentions that its construction has begun in 2018 and it is slowly progressing:

> On 31 January 2018, Germany granted Nord Stream 2 a permit for
>   construction and operation in German waters and landfall areas near
>   Lubmin. In May 2018 construction started at the Greifswald end
>   point. By September 2018, 18 miles of the underwater pipeline
>   construction were completed.

[Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/arielcohen/2018/06/18/russias-nord-stream-ii-pipeline-is-ukraines-worst-nightmare/#220de6743524) argues that this project is very problematic to Ukraine since it would diminish its importance in gas transportation from Russia to European Union countries:

> Ukraine is Russia’s gateway into European gas markets. Of the 193
>   billion cubic meters (bcm) Russia’s state-owned Gazprom pumped
>   westward in 2017 –  nearly 40 percent of Europe’s total supply – **93
>   bcm transited via Ukraine**. Moscow, however, wants to change that,
>   diminishing Ukraine’s transit role. Kyiv, on the other hand, hopes to
>   maintain the current arrangement, as transit revenues contribute some
>   USD 2-3 billion annually to the Ukrainian economy (roughly 3 percent
>   of GDP) and act as a buffer against further Russian aggression.

On the other hand, [Ukraine-EU relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukraine%E2%80%93European_Union_relations) seem to quite tight:

> Relations between the European Union (EU) and Ukraine are shaped
>   through the Ukraine–European Union Association Agreement and the Deep
>   and Comprehensive Free Trade Area (DCFTA). Ukraine is a priority
>   partner within the Eastern Partnership and the European Neighbourhood
>   Policy (ENP). The EU is seeking an increasingly close relationship
>   with Ukraine, **going beyond co-operation, to gradual economic
>   integration and deepening of political co-operation**

I am wondering how does EU ensures political consistency between Nord Stream II and its relationship with Ukraine since they seem to be contradictory.

**Question:** How does Nord Stream II project fit with Ukraine-EU relationship?

Comment: How does Nord stream 2 able to relates to EU-Ukraine relations at all?! It may affect Russian-Ukraine relations only, if any.

Comment: @user2501323 - Nord Stream 2 is built with support from various EU countries and clearly affects Ukraine.

Comment: Totally agreed with you. But do you read yourself? "affects Ukraine" - absolutely yes. But affect relations with Ukraine? In what way ever?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nord Stream 2 takes away [the leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russia%E2%80%93Ukraine_gas_disputes) Ukraine holds over the EU. Since a lot of Europe's natural gas transits the Ukraine on its way from Russia to the west, the Ukraine can basically [block large parts of Europe's gas supply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2009_Russia%E2%80%93Ukraine_gas_dispute).

Thus, Nord Stream 2 is an effort to diversify the transit routes for Russian natural gas.

Answer (score 0):

In no way.

Let's see the benefits of Nord Stream 2:

- for Germany: becoming Europe's natural gas hub.
- for EU gas consumers: lower prices, because no transit countries, only Germany as a hub.

Let's see structure and amounts of EU imports from "priority partner within the Eastern Partnership":

- http://ec.europa.eu/trade/policy/countries-and-regions/countries/ukraine/ - general information, note the total size of 0.9% EU trade.
- ukraine exports mainly consists of raw materials and agricultural products - from open sources, searching for a links.

Thus, I don't see **any** possible penalties for EU-Ukraine relations. Really, at all. I don't ever see strong relations, other than "Minsk treaties". Ukraine is a consumer of EU investments, World Bank credits and EU support programs. But it is a bit one-side relations. Pluses of Nord Stream 2 specified to add an argument for EU to still use it, besides of Ukraine losses on it.

The only possible result - Ukraine may fall unstable after its GDP falls further, but it is not a problem of relations, it is a problem of Poland and Hungary borders security from refugees and problem of EU investments into Ukraine.

Comment: -1: This post does not even attempt to answer the question. Having benefits for Germany and EU from the new pipeline does not automatically mean no impact to EU-Ukraine relations. Also, the post is full of extraordinary claims, and the poster fails to provide sufficient evidence for backing it.

Comment: Extraordinary claims - don't think so. First two are logical. Ukraine imports? I don't think that describing it as in post is "extraordinary". Wow, you even vote to delete)) Don't think, that relations between EU and the Ukraine are something more than one-side credits and minimal trade.

Comment: "This post does not even attempt to answer the question." - I answered it in a very strict way, there is just no relations to impact.)